# Referencing custom classes in an argument of a member function prototype from other custom classes. What if it becomes circular?

Tags: c++, class, prototype, forward-declaration

I get that forward declarations of classes must include the prototype of each member function. But when if an argument for one has the data type of another class you have defined. What if argument A references class B, and the B -> C, and then finally C -> A. You then have a circular order, and you can't put the definitions in order to allow for passing a class as an argument type.

Comment: Forward declarations does not require any member function prototypes at all. You are mixing it up with a class definition. A forward declaration is nothing more then `class Foo;`

Comment: Well, in that specific case just define `CmdRoot` first and all is good since `CmdRoot` doesn't reference `Player`.